# With and Without Sharing Keywords

Tags: sharing-keywords

What is the meaning of "current user" with regard to the definition of with sharing keyword given below? Please explain in detail.

The with sharing keyword allows you to specify that the sharing rules for the current user be taken into account for a class.

Answer (score 2):

Current user means the user who is executing an action, like user is opening a visualforce or performing a CRUD operation on an object.

You can refer an extensive list in my answer as below:
[Types of execution - System mode or User Mode?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172060/types-of-execution-system-mode-or-user-mode)

Comment: Not the person who is writing the code? It is person who is performing some action on that page. Correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: can you please let me know the link where I can find good examples on this for better understanding.